# CSS working in codepen not in jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I've got [this pen](http://codepen.io/stefanjudis/pen/gkHwJ), which I'm migrating to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/wjs86t5a/)

There is no external `CSS` library and `d3.js` is referenced in both of them.

Where am I missing?

Comment: It is there, in pen if you click settings you will see the d3 import and click embed in fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the SCSS setting in your fiddle. Click the gear next to CSS, and choose SCSS from the drop down.